# How to use Tagedit plugin in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, tags

I want to add the Tagedit plugin in my project to add names to the textbox.
My requirements are:
1. The textbox should have autocomplete for existing names.
2. It should able to accept new names if not found in existing data, similar to the tags textbox in stack overflow

Below are the links for the plugin:

http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/

http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/playground.html

For this purpose i have used a ajax JSON & webservice to get the values from the database

Step1: Added Controls to the aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpNames" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <img alt="" src="" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hfJsonData" />
    </form>
```

Step2: Added related links of jquery and CSS to the page

```
<link href="App_Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Styles/CRMStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="App_Scripts/JqPlugins/Autocomplete/Tagedit-master/css/jquery.tagedit.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="App_Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../App_Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="App_Scripts/JqPlugins/Autocomplete/Tagedit-master/js/jquery.tagedit.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Step3: Added script to get data from webservice

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            fnGetemployess();
            var localdata = [$("#hfJsonData").val()];
            debugger;
            $('#<%=txtEmpNames.ClientID %>').tagedit({ autocompleteOptions: { source: localdata} });

        });
        function fnGetemployess() {
            var jsonData;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:7253/Webservice.asmx/Getemployees",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    fnArrangedata(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('Failed to get employees');
                }
            });


            var array = $("#hfJsonData").val();

        }

        function fnArrangedata(list) {
            var array = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                array.push("{\"value\":\"" + list[i].ename + "\",\"empno\":\"" + list[i].empno + "\",\"sal\":\"" + list[i].sal + "\"}");
            }

            $("#hfJsonData").val(array);
        }
    </script>
```

Step4: Added webservice Code to  get data from database

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
  public List<empCls> Getemployees()
        {
            List<empCls> Employees = new List<empCls>();
            List<emp> emps = new CRMTestDataContext().emps.ToList();
            foreach (var item in emps)
            {
                empCls em = new empCls
                {
                    ename = item.ename,
                    empno = item.empno,
                    sal=item.sal
                };
                Employees.Add(em);
            }
            return Employees;
        }
```

Step5: I am getting the following results from Webservice

```
    <ArrayOfEmpCls>

<empCls><empno>1</empno><ename>JOHNSON</ename><sal>18000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>2</empno><ename>HARDING</ename><sal>52000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>3</empno><ename>TAFT</ename><sal>25000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>4</empno><ename>HOOVER</ename><sal>27000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>5</empno><ename>LINCOLN</ename><sal>22500.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>6</empno><ename>GARFIELD</ename><sal>54000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>7</empno><ename>POLK</ename><sal>25000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>8</empno><ename>GRANT</ename><sal>32000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>9</empno><ename>JACKSON</ename><sal>75000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>10</empno><ename>FILLMORE</ename><sal>56000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>11</empno><ename>ADAMS</ename><sal>34000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>12</empno><ename>WASHINGTON</ename><sal>18000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>13</empno><ename>MONROE</ename><sal>30000.00</sal>
</empCls><empCls><empno>14</empno><ename>ROOSEVELT</ename><sal>35000.00</sal>

</empCls></ArrayOfEmpCls>
```

Step6: I have changed the webservice response into jquery array by using step 3

```
{"value":"JOHNSON","empno":"1","sal":"18000"},
{"value":"HARDING","empno":"2","sal":"52000"},
{"value":"TAFT","empno":"3","sal":"25000"},
{"value":"HOOVER","empno":"4","sal":"27000"},
{"value":"LINCOLN","empno":"5","sal":"22500"},
{"value":"GARFIELD","empno":"6","sal":"54000"},
{"value":"POLK","empno":"7","sal":"25000"},
{"value":"GRANT","empno":"8","sal":"32000"},
{"value":"JACKSON","empno":"9","sal":"75000"},
{"value":"FILLMORE","empno":"10","sal":"56000"},
{"value":"ADAMS","empno":"11","sal":"34000"},
{"value":"WASHINGTON","empno":"12","sal":"18000"},
{"value":"MONROE","empno":"13","sal":"30000"},
{"value":"ROOSEVELT","empno":"14","sal":"35000"}
```

Now when running the page neither I am getting an error nor the plugin is working.
I request all the members to help me out in this case. 
Thanks in advance for the help.